# NSArray componentsJoinedByString with condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

For example, I have an array

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one<true>",@"two<false>",@"three<true>",@"four<false>"];
```

I want the output as NSString using componentsJoinedByString

```
"one<true>'&'two<false>'&&'three<true>'&'four<false>'&&'"
```

That is, in an array if an object contain a value `<true>` it should be joined by `'&'` and if an array value contain a value `<false>` it should be joined by `'&&'`.

I know, I can run a for loop and using if condition, I can achieve the output. But I'm looking for other efficient way to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean code efficient. Your loop can be just as runtime efficient as your imagined solution. It seems unlikely you can actually use your imagined solution and be either code or runtime efficient because that isn't what `componentsJoinedByString` does. So, just write the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It may be help

you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

for ex:

```
yourArrayJoinString=[yourArrayJoinString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<true>" withString:@"<true>'&'"];
yourArrayJoinString=[yourArrayJoinString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<false>" withString:@"<false>'&&'"];
```

Comment: or use componentsJoinedByString with "&&"
and than replace "true>'&" with "true>'"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one<true>",@"two<false>",@"three<true>",@"four<false>" ,nil];
NSString *str = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<false>" withString:@"<false>'&&'"];
str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<true>" withString:@"<true>'&'"];
```